# RapidMiner: Ability to classify based off user set support threshold?

Tags: classification, svm, rapidminer

I am have built a small text analysis model that is classifying small text files as either good, bad, or neutral. I was using a Support-Vector Machine as my classifier. However, I was wondering if instead of classifying all three I could classify into either Good or Bad but if the support for that text file is below .7 or some user specified threshold it would classify that text file as neutral. I know this isn't looked at as the best way of doing this, I am just trying to see what would happen if I took a different approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The operator `Drop Uncertain Predictions` might be what you want.

After you have applied your model to some test data, the resulting example set will have a prediction and two new attributes called `confidence(Good)` and `confidence(Bad)`. These confidences are between 0 and 1 and for the two class case they will sum to 1 for each example within the example set. The highest confidence dictates the value of the prediction.

The `Drop Uncertain Predictions` operator requires a `min confidence` parameter and will set the prediction to missing if the maximum confidence it finds is below this value (you can also have different confidences for different class values for more advanced investigations).

You could then use the `Replace Missing Values` operator to change all missing predictions to be a text value of your choice.